# All models of the successor function

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, model-theory

I'm having problems understanding proofs to similar questions so I want to check if my understanding is correct. The version I have uses three axioms:

1. $s$ is injective
2. Everything except $0$ is in the image of $s$
3. $s$ is cycle-free

**Statement:** All models $M$ of the successor function in the signature $L= \{0, s \}$ look like $M\cong \mathbb{N} \cup (X\times \mathbb{Z})$.

**Proof sketch:**

1. By axiom 1 and since $0$ is in the signature, we get $\mathbb{N}$ by repeatedly applying $s$.
2. By axiom 2, for any $x\in X$ the element $x$ itself is in the image of $s$, hence it has a predecessor. It obviously also has a successor. Repeated induction (?) returns a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.
3. Repeat step $2$ for every $x\in X \implies |M| = |\mathbb{N}|+(|X|\cdot |\mathbb{Z}|)=\omega + |X|\cdot \omega = \omega(|X|+1)$.

Other proofs I've read use axiom 3 and equivalence classes instead. Could someone clarify in a bit more detail how it works?

Comment: Are you asking how to make your proof work or how to prove it using equivalence classes instead?  The main issue with your proof is what precisely you mean by "Repeat step $2$ for every $x\in X$".

Comment: @EricWofsey I guess my proof doesn't work because I don't understand how equivalence classes work. So an explanation of equivalence classes would suffice.

Comment: Isn't $\lambda$-calculus a good framework to study this function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your proof you used $X$, but you don't know at that point what $X$ is.

> 3. Repeat step $2$ for every $x\in X$ [...]

How can you repeat step $2$ for every $x∈X$ without knowing what $X$ is?

In a sense, the equivalent classes method is a way to find this $X$.

---

Take $M$ and define $\sim$ as $a\sim b$ whenever it is possible to get from $a$ to $b$ by repeatedly applying $s$ or repeatedly applying $s^{-1}$ finitely many times.

Indeed $a\sim a$ because $0\in\omega$, $a\sim b\sim c\implies a\sim c$ because getting from $a$ to $b$ and then from $b$ to $c$ requires "amount of steps from $a$ to $b$"$+$"amount of steps from $b$ to $c$" which is finite, and $a\sim b\implies b\sim a$ by inverting the steps from getting from $a$ to $b$.

Now $X$ will be exactly $M/\sim\setminus[0]_\sim$.

To see that you need to show that for all $a\in X$ we have $a\cong \mathbb Z$ and $[0]_\sim≅\mathbb N$.

To finish the proof, choose from each $a\in X$ some arbitrary $0_a∈a$ and define $F:M≅ω+X×(ω^*+ω)$ by $F\restriction [0]_\sim$ being the isomorphism you found in the previous paragraph, and $F\restriction a$ for $a\in X$ be the unique isomorphism from $a$ to $\mathbb Z$ extending $F(0_a)=0$, and prove that $F$ is a full isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, so assuming $X= \{ a, b, c \}$ the equivalence relation takes care of situations such as $a \sim b \sim c$ and it's actually only $\mathbb{Z} \cup \mathbb{N}$ kind of isomorphism type? This makes sense if that's the case. I was wondering if they should rather generate $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

Comment: @averagemathenjoyer I am not sure I understand your question, you don't get to choose $X$, but given a model $M$ there exists some $X$ that is generated from $M$. (It is possible to generate $M$ from $X$, but that is a different question from what you asked)